# Service is not getting disconnected on calling unBindService()

Tags: java, android, binding, sdk, connection

i have implemented and inter-process communication using Binder in my android project. My activity & service are running the same application. i have disconnected from the service by calling unbindService(intent) & the service is destroyed. But am able to call the public method which is already destroyed... how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you unbind the connection of service, there is a chance that another connection still existed somewhere within the application. Therefore it's the best practice if you call stopService() in activity to destroy the service or stopSelf inside the Service itself.

Comment: if this is the case, while we are stopping the service by calling stopService() or stopSelf(),then there is no need to call unbind service right? we can directly make the connection object to null ryt?

Comment: yeah by calling upon stopService() and stopSelf() in the service all connection will be terminated thus your connection object would be null.